# Move the pointer along an array, n number of times

Tags: ruby

I want to move through just two indexes of an array. Something along these lines

```
iterate_amount = 2
array = [2,4,6,7]

iterate_amount.times do |x|
    puts x
end #=> 2,4
```

I just don't know how I can place the 'array' in the loop to tell the interpreter this is the array I want to move through two indexes.

Comment: geez what is people's problem?

Comment: that is likely a whole other question, and possibly something that could be answered in Stack Exchange _Philosophy_ though it is  'for those interested in logical reasoning' which means this question may not fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Array#take`  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-take

```
>> a = [2,4,6,7]
=> [2, 4, 6, 7]
>> a.take 2
=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: either way will give you an array, which you you can iterate over.  The question I have, which isn't 100% clear from the  wording is does OP care about where the iterator is at the end

Comment: @steenslag where do you see `take` accepting a block?   `first(n) → new_ary` and `take(n) → new_ary`  pretty much do the same thing,  Can  also do `a[0,2]` or `a.slice(0,2)` or `a.slice(0...2)`  but the all still give you an array back.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle):

```
array = [2,4,6,7]
array.cycle(2) do |x|
  puts x
end
```

prints

```
2
4
6
7
2
4
6
7
```

**UPDATE**

Use `Array#[]` with specifying start, length  OR  with specifying range.

```
>> array[0, 2]
=> [2, 4]
>> array[0..1]
=> [2, 4]
>> array[0...2]
=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: Cool. One of those methods I saw in lists, but never bothered to find out what it did . . .

Comment: Ah sorry guys, badly worded question. That's not quite what I meant. I've appended it now.